# How to ensure a function is executed before any ctor of global variables?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, global-variables, standards

In VC++ and GCC, `main` is not the real entry point of a program; but we can reset the program's real entry point by compiler arguments `-ENTRY` and `-Wl,-eentry`.

For example: The real entry piont by default is `mainCRTStartup` in VC++; that is to say, `mainCRTStartup` will be called before `main`.

My question is: **If I have several global C++ variables in my program, do they guaranteed NOT to be initialized until `mainCRTStartup` is finished?**

> **Problem Background:**
>
> I have a closed-source framework, which has a bug in its global
>   variable ctors. I can fix the bug if my fixing code can execute before the
>   global variable ctors.

Comment: Global variables are initialized *by* `mainCRTStartup`. That's one of the tasks it performs, before calling `main`. `mainCRTStartup` never actually "finishes" - it calls `exit()` when `main` returns.

Answer (score 1):

How? You plan to hook mainCRTStartup()?  In that case, you can run your code and call mainCRTStartup() from the hook. (sorry, can't comment yet)